# Xamarin Android SDK Manager doesn't save locations

Tags: xamarin, configuration, visual-studio-2017, android-sdk-tools

Using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin, I installed the [**Xamarin Android SDK Manager**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinAndroidSDKManager) to replace the default Android SDK Manager, which is now deprecated.

Then I updated JDK to the current x64 version and, using the Xamarin SDK Manager, I installed the most recent version of Android NDK.

I now want to update the locations of these SDK's in the Xamarin Android SDK Manager, Locations tab like so:

[image: Updating locations of SDKs]

Yet, every time I restart the tool, the locations are **reset**. It also keeps telling me there's *2 components to install*, yet when I do, it doesn't complain about any failure.

[image: Locations are reset]

I have tried running as Admin and cannot seem to figure out what is wrong. Log files seem to be non existent. Is there anyone who has the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: Is this something you have considered bringing up in [Xamarin's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/)? I think that's the best place for getting support for issues like these.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll go ahead and file a bug report there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed in 0.1.76.
See https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58319 for details.

Download the newest version here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinAndroidSDKManager